# Is possible storyboard work with keyEvent on corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have onKeyMenu function to handle keyEvent, but when I call gotoScene method the app just exit. what is the problem?

this my code

```
local function  onKeyMenu  (event) 
    local phase = event.phase
    local keyName = event.keyName
    if (event.phase == "up" and (event.keyName=="back" or event.keyName=="menu")) then
        if keyName == "menu" then
            showMenu()
        elseif keyName == "back" then           
            storyboard.gotoScene("menu", "fade") <--- cause app exit
        end
    end
    return true
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onKeyMenu )
```

Comment: I had the same issue. It looks like the you get some error on Coronas side, when you try to call gotoScene() in the event handlers of any native stuff (like onKey, alertdialog button, etc). I still havent found a solution for this.

Comment: wew, I think so, anyway what have you done to solve this problem? are just skip the problem? or you have alternative way?
I'm just stuck with this.

Comment: I have not found a solution. What i wanted is the back button to work, like in any other android application, but i simply ended up blocking it, by returning true in the event handler, and placing a back button on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing any errors in your logs?  It could either be an error in menu.lua, or what is more likely the case, in the scene you are leaving, you have a timer running, a transition.to that has an onComplete handler, an audio track that has an onComplete handler and when you leave that scene, there is nothing to complete and your app is crashing.

Comment: I can't see error cause I have run it on my device indeed the emulator doesn't support native key, and I think there is no error on menu.lua, I have to try call menu.lua with button and it run smoothly.